# Android Google Map CircleOptions Circles Show's Weird Lines with Circle

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

I am facing weird behavior when adding multiple Circles on Google Maps. It is working fine on the Majority of devices but this issue is mostly occurring on Android 10 (API level 29) Like Samsung S10.

Code For adding Circles on Google Map:

```
for (locations in mLocationsList) {
   val circleOptions = CircleOptions()
      .center(LatLng(locations.latitude, locations.longitude))
      .radius(affectedRadius)
      .strokeWidth(2f)
      .strokeColor(Color.RED)
      .fillColor(Color.parseColor("#07FF0000"))
      .clickable(true)
    
   googleMap?.addCircle(circleOptions)
}
```

This is the result I am getting.

[image: Result Getting]

**NOTE:** The same code works for many devices with a Lower version than Android 10.

[image: Expected Result]

Comment: did you find any solution for this? I really need it

Answer (score 0):

Its really weird. Try to turn off hardware acceleration in Manifest `<application>` section:

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="false" ...>
```

or in source code:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
    mapView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for your reply, But after your suggestion, the lines are still there.

Answer (score 0):

You can create circles using polygon:

```
private var polygon: Polygon? = null
private var center: LatLng? = null
private var radius: Double? = null

private fun addCircle(center: LatLng, radius: Double) {
    if (this.center != center || this.radius != radius) {
        this.center = center
        this.radius = radius

        val points = ArrayList<LatLng>()

        var degree = 0.0
        while (degree <= 360.0) {
            points.add(SphericalUtil.computeOffset(center, radius, degree))
            degree += 0.1
        }

        if (polygon == null) {
            val fillColor = Color.argb(100, 130, 182, 228)
            val strokeColor = Color.argb(255, 130, 182, 228)
            
            polygon = mMap?.addPolygon(
                PolygonOptions()
                    .addAll(points)
                    .fillColor(fillColor)
                    .strokeColor(strokeColor)
                    .strokeWidth(1f.dp())
                    .zIndex(Float.MAX_VALUE)
            )
        } else {
            polygon?.points = points
        }
    }
}
```

or you can convert it to a custom circle class using this approach.